# Facebox open from ajax respond text not work properly

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a problem with jQuery plugin "facebox".

**here is the script in php**

```
echo"<a  href='confirm.php' rel='facebox' id='$row[mynr]' onclick=\"activatefacebox('$row[mynr]'); return false;\" ></a>";
```

**In javascript**

```
function activatefacebox(id_post) {
    var sss="#"+id_post;

     jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

      $('#sss').facebox({
        loading_image : '../img/ajax-loader.gif',

      }) 
    })

}
```

**My problem is :** The first click it´s not work, you have to click it again and it will open the facebox, but with 2 boxes. And when you click the link the box will increase from 2 to 3 to 4 etc.

I have no idea how to fix this. But it work fine with pure php without ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Did this code solve your problems?

**here is the script in php**

```
echo "<a  href='confirm.php' rel='facebox' id='{$row[mynr]}' class=\"myFacebox\" ></a>";
```

**In javascript**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('.myFacebox').click(function(){
             $(this).facebox({
                   loading_image : '../img/ajax-loader.gif',
             }) 
             return false;
      });
})
```

Comment: Hei cyper ..thank you for your answer ! It actually work if I do this way.
But the reason I spesified the id with the $row[mynr] is because I have many links to use the facebox..which means I need differences id to work with it.

ANd this is the problem.